# Django not using databases from settings.py

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm a few weeks into Python/Django and encountering an annoying problem. I have some existing databases set up in settings.py, everything looks good, I've even accessed the databases using connections[].cursor()

But the databases (and data) are not making their way into models that I want to use, despite doing the makemigrations and migrate commands. I was able to use py manage.py inspectdb --database-dbname and copied that class information manually into my models.py, but that didn't work either (typing py manage.py inspectdb on its own does not pull up these databases, I was only able to view by that --database extension). So I'm stumped, as it seems I'm doing all the right steps but not able to use these existing databases in Django.

Any other hints and steps I can take are welcome!

Comment: Please share the settings.py file

Comment: `
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'strides': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'stravridedatabase.sqlite3'),
    },
    'ridedb':{
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'ridedb.sqlite3'),
    }
}`

Comment: Using multiple databases in one django project is not something you'd normally do. What's the purpose that you want to use multiple different databases? Read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/) to understand how to use multiple dbs and what the implications are.

Comment: Well, I had the databases already from a python file I was using to extract bike ride data from Strava, so I was just trying to bring in those records into Django. I'm not opposed to just using Django if I can figure out a way to transfer the data from the existing database to Django's default, so I'd gladly take any advice on how to actually migrate all the data

Answer (score 0):

(Almost) all the tutorials, examples, and third-party app you'll find on the internet, and most of the Django documentation assume you use **one database** for your app. That's because it's fairly tricky and unusual to use multiple databases in one app.

But it's not impossible to use multiple databases and [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/) contains instructions on how to do this and what changes you'll need to make to make it work.

IMO, these are the pre-conditions to use multiple databases in one project:

- The databases contain explicitly unrelated information, i.e. you won't have SQL relationships between tables in different databases. One database may contain a table with a column that maps to a column in a table in another database, but they aren't explicit (no ForeignKey or ManyToManyField in your models).
- You don't need to mix databases in one query: This basically derives from the previous condition. It just means that if you need to get objects from one database that depend on the rows coming from another database, you establish the relationship in python. E.g. fetching as list of names from one database and using that list to filter a queryset on the other database.

For example, if you have an existing database that contains Strava routes (which are regularly updated via some external mechanism) and your app is a broader app that helps users getting to know their neighbourhood where they can recommend locations and things to do, being able to offer a list of routes with a starting point nearby might be something you'd want to show.

Now that you know this, the way to go is described in the doc linked above:

- [Create a database router](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/multi-db/#automatic-database-routing) so that queries for certain models are automatically routed to the correct database. E.g. `Route.objects.filter(start_city=city)` would automatically fetch routes from your Strava routes database.
- If you need to save information about a route in your app, save it in a model in the default database and use a unique identifier of the route that will map to the strava database. Use separate queries (no relationships) to fetch information about a specific route.

That being said, if the Strava database is not regularly updated via 3rd channels and its purpose is just to pre-populate your default database, then export the data from the Strava database as json and import it into your django db using [`manage.py loaddata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-loaddata) or [a migration file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/writing-migrations/#migrating-data-between-third-party-apps), the latter being more flexible as to the structure of the json file.

Comment: Thanks, I had come across some of this and might have to keep going down the rabbit hole. Alternatively, a third option I'm exploring and would probably be the best thing going forward is figuring out how to take my python file (which basically works with Strava's API to download my ride data in the form of watts, heartrate, time in seconds and ride date) and just have the data load directly to Django database. My original testing had me putting data into a pandas dataframe, so if I could alter my code to just write the dataframe to the Django default database, that would be ideal

Comment: That third option sounds like the more simple and logical way to go.